# Did I use "Form" appropriately in my sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The water loss from earthen irrigation canals is usually divided in to two parts. 1 parts is infiltration or seepage, the other important part is evaporation from water surface.
 While in a humid climate the evaporation is not remarkable, in arid climate it is very important. 
I wanted to know if I have used the  verb "form" appropriately in the following sentence.

**In arid regions,the evaporation from the water surface forms significant/remarkable part of water loss in irrigation canals**

cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure if "forms" is the word you want. Perhaps "comprises"?

Comment: @Glorfindel But it doesn't *form* a significant part. It's **is** a significant part. *Comprises* does a better job of conveying that fact.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, because looking at a dictionary definition, I would agree with Catija and laureapresa that "to form" is not the right verb here. However, I have used it this way myself, so I did a quick Google search for the exact phrase "forms a part of" and got over 33 million results. Many of those are from legal documents and medical texts, two of the most heavily proofread types of documents you can find in English.

So is it correct? That's a question for grammarians, and may spark an argument between descriptivists and prescriptivists, but it is definitely accepted.

But to use it correctly, "part" needs to take an article. In this case,

> "forms **a** significant part of **the** water loss in irrigation canals."

You could get away without using the definite article in front of "water loss", since you're talking about a broad, general concept, but it definitely sounds better with the article.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if *to form* is used appropriately, and I'd say it is not.
I understand perfectly what you mean, but it is not the right verb for the job: I checked Ngrams for "form part of" or similar combinations and I did not find any occurrences (unless I am doing something wrong).

I would suggest using *constitute* (added a couple of minor edits too):

> In arid regions, the evaporation from the water surface constitutes a significant part/portion of the water loss in irrigation canals

But IMHO the best way would be *[to account for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/account+for)*

> In arid regions, the evaporation from the water surface accounts for a significant portion of the water loss in irrigation canals
>
> In arid regions, the evaporation from the water surface accounts for most of the water loss in irrigation canals